# variable not defined when using in threading

Tags: python, multithreading

I am beginner to Python. I defined a variable when using threading but when I started the thread and asked the value of the variable it gave me an error. Here is the minimum, reproducible example.Please help as soon as possible

```
def start_thread(target):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=target)
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()
def example():
    a='hello'
start_thread(example)
print(a)
```

And I says variable not defined

Comment: Please add full error traceback, so we can better help you!

Answer (score 0):

The variable `a` is undefined because it is local to the function `example()`. If you want it accessible outside that function, make it global to the file - or (better) make it a class-level private variable that you access via a getter function.